# ORA-00942: table or view does not exist on Materialized View refresh

Tags: sql

I encounter an error whenever I refresh my Materialized view, so I created a PIPELINE function and left join it to my Main table, the creation of Materialized view runs smoothly, but when I tried to do a refresh, then the error message appeared.

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Please, need help on this.

```
create materialized view mv_test as 
SELECT
    id,
    id1,
    id2,
    id3,
    id4,
    id5,
    lpad(substr(ab.column_value, 3), 4, '0') ab
FROM
    tbl1 t1 left join 
            TABLE ( split_str_by_delim(t1.id1, '|')) ab on substr(ab.column_value,1,2) = 
'AB'
WHERE id2= sysdate;
```

Refresh:

```
begin
    dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST','C');
end;
/
```

I also tried the snapshot refresh, and still doesn't work.

```
BEGIN 
    DBMS_SNAPSHOT.REFRESH( '"MV_TEST"','C'); 
end;
```

Below is the error I encounter.

```
Materialized view MV_TEST created.


Error starting at line : 22 in command -
begin
    dbms_mview.refresh('MV_TEST','C');
end;
Error report -
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3020
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2432
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 88
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 253
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2413
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 2976
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3263
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT_KKXRCA", line 3295
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SNAPSHOT", line 16
ORA-06512: at line 2
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Edit: Added my Function PIPELINE and TYPE

Type:

```
create or replace TYPE split_tbl as TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767);
```

Function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION split_str_by_delim (p_list VARCHAR2, p_del 
VARCHAR2)
   RETURN split_tbl
   PIPELINED IS
   l_idx PLS_INTEGER;
   l_list VARCHAR2 (32767) := p_list;
   l_value VARCHAR2 (32767);
BEGIN
   LOOP
      l_idx := INSTR (l_list, p_del);

      IF l_idx > 0 THEN
         PIPE ROW (SUBSTR (l_list, 1, l_idx - 1));
         l_list := SUBSTR (l_list, l_idx + LENGTH (p_del));
      ELSE
         PIPE ROW (l_list);
         EXIT;
      END IF;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN;
END split_str_by_delim;
```

regards,
NelzKi

Comment: Is the view created in a different schema than `AMLAETL`?

Comment: no, same schema.

Comment: The user that runs refresh, is it the owner of amlaetl.lkp_tslog_otc ?

Comment: yes, same owner. I only use AMLAETL schema for creation and refresh of mview.

Comment: Does the MV query run as a straight SELECT statement?

Comment: yes, straight SELECT, 

also, i just check that the issue only encounter when using a ANSI join.

Comment: but I need to LEFT JOIN my PIPELINE function :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, It works! I just added this additional join and it works like magic.

```
left join dual on 1=1
```

materialized view refresh has been successful.

Full Script:

```
create materialized view mv_test as 
SELECT
    id,
    id1,
    id2,
    id3,
    id4,
    id5,
    lpad(substr(ab.column_value, 3), 4, '0') ab
FROM
    tbl1 t1 left join 
            TABLE ( split_str_by_delim(t1.id1, '|')) ab on substr(ab.column_value,1,2) = 'AB'
    left join dual on 1=1
WHERE id2 = sysdate;
```

NelzKi